# for Loop Through String in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, programming-loop

I'm trying to write a loop in VHDL that will print a certain message on an LCD screen.

I have predefined the following:

```
constant LCDHP  :integer range 0 to 1056:=  1056;--horizontal period
constant LCDHPW :integer range 0 to 30  :=  30  ;--horizontal pulse-width
constant LCDHBP :integer range 0 to 16  :=  16  ;--horizontal back-porch
constant LCDHFP :integer range 0 to 210 :=  210 ;--horizontal front-porch
constant LCDVP  :integer range 0 to 525 :=  525 ;--vertical period
constant LCDVPW :integer range 0 to 13  :=  13  ;--vertical pulse-width
constant LCDVBP :integer range 0 to 10  :=  10  ;--vertical back-porch
constant LCDVFP :integer range 0 to 22  :=  22  ;--vertical front-porch
type coordinate is record
    H:integer range LCDHP'range;
    V:integer range LCDVP'range;
end record;
constant TP:coordinate:=(H=>LCDHP-LCDHFP,V=>LCDVP-LCDVFP);--text-position
function char2ascii(char:character)return std_logic_vector is
begin
    case char is
    when'0'=>return conv_std_logic_vector(16,7);
    when'1'=>return conv_std_logic_vector(17,7);
    when'2'=>return conv_std_logic_vector(18,7);
    when'3'=>return conv_std_logic_vector(19,7);
    ...
end function char2ascii;
constant message0:string(1 to 60):=   "Hello, I'm Doron Behar and I'm the developer of this project";
```

I will not deliver all the content of this file because it's very long and most of it is not relevant. Yet, I **have** managed to print text on the screen with a different method:

The standard (and *simple*) method is to write a asynchronous process. (It could also be written in a parallel way without a process and using `when else`) I'll show an example for the standard method:

```
process(pixel_row,pixel_column)
begin
    if pixel_row>TP.H - 16 and pixel_row <= TP.H then
        if pixel_column <= TP.V - 0 * 8 and pixel_column > TP.V - 1 * 8 then
            char_code <= char2ascii(message0(1));
        elsif pixel_column <= TP.V - 1 * 8 and pixel_column > TP.V - 2 * 8 then
            char_code <= char2ascii(message0(2));
        elsif pixel_column <= TP.V - 2 * 8 and pixel_column > TP.V - 3 * 8 then
            char_code <= char2ascii(message0(3));
        elsif--well you get the idea..
            char_code <= ...;
        else
            char_code <= char2ascii(' ');
        end if;
    else
        char_code <= char2ascii(' ');
    end if;
end process;
```

This is not a smart way to print the text, it's good if the string is not long and it's working but in the case of a full sentence it's not very efficient because it requires to write 2*message'length (which is 120 in my example) lines for 1 message.

The solution I thought of was using a loop:

```
process(pixel_row,pixel_column)
begin
    for i in message0 'range loop
        if pixel_row>TP.H-16 and pixel_row<=TP.H then
            if pixel_column<=TP.V-(i-1)*8 and pixel_column>TP.V-i*8 then
                char_code<=char2ascii(message0(i));
            else
                char_code<=char2ascii(' ');
            end if;
        else
            char_code<=char2ascii(' ');
        end if;
    end loop;
end process;
```

From some reason it just doesn't work! I'm not sure what is the reason why I see nothing on the screen while I **can** print text with the 1st method.

I've also tried using `for generate`:

```
txt:for i in message0'range generate
    char_code<= char2ascii(message0(i)) when
        pixel_row>TP.H-16 and pixel_row<=TP.H and pixel_column<=TP.V-(i-1)*8 and pixel_column>TP.V-i*8
    else        char2ascii(' ');
end generate txt;
```

But I got the following errors:

```
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "char_code[6]" at display-control.vhd(339)
Error (10029): Constant driver at display-control.vhd(339)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "char_code[5]" at display-control.vhd(339)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "char_code[3]" at display-control.vhd(339)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "char_code[2]" at display-control.vhd(339)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "char_code[1]" at display-control.vhd(339)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "char_code[0]" at display-control.vhd(339)
```

Is there something wrong with the way I treat the string's range? Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do or should I think of a totally different method?

Any Help Appreciated :)

Comment: You are saying your design is working, but how? Processes without sensitivity lists are not allowed in synthesis and driving a LC-Display bus without a clock won't work either...

Comment: you are right @Paebbels, I've made an edit. I dropped off the sensitivity list originally in order to spare some of the content from the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a loop here. But your process does need to generate `i` (the index into the message) from `TP.V`, probably through division by 8.

Something like:

```
process()
   variable i : natural range 0 to LCDVP/8;
begin
    if pixel_row>TP.H - 16 and pixel_row <= TP.H then
        i := pixel_column / 8;
        if i <= message0'high then
            char_code <= char2ascii(message0(i));
        else
            char_code <= char2ascii(' ');
        end if;
    else
        char_code <= char2ascii(' ');
    end if;
end process;
```

You may object to the use of division in synthesis, but I've never seen a synthesis tool out there (this century at least) that can't make the obvious optimisation for a fixed division by 8.

I'll note the you are also making life unnecessarily hard for yourself with the declaration of `char2ascii` : its body should be pretty much a one-liner too.

Comment: `TP.V` is constant. It doesn't make sense to write `i:=TP.V/8` because it's just gonna make `i` equal to a certain number and that's it.

Comment: Details, details.... (Edited)